# Python Tornado: WSGI module missing?

Tags: python, flask, tornado

I did a `pip install tornado` but I cannot run the following code because WSGI module is missing??

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/wsgi-standalone/

```
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from myapp import app

http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
http_server.listen(5000)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: Hi, could you please paste the error and traceback. That could be helpful.

Comment: ImportError: No module named wsgi

Comment: are you sure that the install was successful. Can you locate the module in the library on the file system?

Comment: it's inside the site-packages directory and I ran it with sudo pip install tornado...

Comment: ok. and what about the wsgi module inside tornado. it could be a file or a folder. is that present?
If not, it would be better if you remove the module using pip uninstall and then add it again and try. Thats just for safe measure. But your problem might have something to do with it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your file is named tornado.py, it will try to import things from that file instead of the directory on site-packages.  This is probably the most common source of "no module named X" ImportErrors.  Rename the file and it should work.

After you rename the file from `tornado.py` to something else, also delete the `tornado.pyc` that got created.