# ImportError: No module named tornado.wsgi

Tags: python

I am running python 2.7 on ubuntu 12.04. I did `pip install tornado` in a virtual environment and python reports that it was a successful installation. But when I run the code in the file `tserver.py` I get the following error:

```
(venv)$ python tserver.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tserver.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
ImportError: No module named tornado.wsgi
```

I found this question describing a very similar problem [Python Tornado: WSGI module missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505495/python-tornado-wsgi-module-missing) -- but my file is not called tornado.py so the answer does not help me.

Comment: perhaps there's something wrong with your init file? Try copying the package into tservers working directory and see if an import will work

Comment: did you find out what the error was? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Had you named the  server file initially as tornado.py ? because,  I had and even after changing i still got that error.

I fixed it after I did a `sudo pip install tornado --upgrade`

After this i closed the terminal and restarted it. Then, in the python interpreter i tried  `import tornado` and the error was gone.

Also also remove any tornado.pyc or tornado.py file in the directory where your application is present