# Python Tornado: ImportError: No module named 'tornado'

Tags: python, tornado

This is my tornado file::

```
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import FallbackHandler, RequestHandler, Application
from flasky import app

class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.write("This message comes from Tornado ^_^")

tr = WSGIContainer(app)

application = Application([
(r"/tornado", MainHandler),
(r".*", FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=tr)),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  application.listen(5000)
  IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Basically I'm running a flask server in Tornado. But I'm getting this error:

> ```
> from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer 
> ImportError: No module named 'tornado'
> ```

I've already gone through this post: [Python Tornado: WSGI module missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505495/python-tornado-wsgi-module-missing)

But my file is not named Tornado.py so that doesn't apply to me.

Please help.

Comment: i assume you have the tornado module installed with `pip install tornado`

Comment: yes, i do have it installed.

Comment: Could PYTHONPATH be the issue? I had similar issue with Flask and I had to set PYTHONPATH but, **sudo pip install** did the job for me (after removing Flask and reinstalling it). Also try installing/reinstalling tornado (try installing it globally)

Comment: I have only one version of python installed on my machine so I doubt thats the reason why i am getting this error message. i did try to install globally but still no dice

Comment: provide output of `pip freeze`

Comment: Output of pip freeze:
backports-abc==0.4
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1
certifi==2015.11.20.1
pymssql==2.1.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.10.0
tornado==4.3

Comment: If on linux, are you running this file with root?

Answer (score 15):

A common problem is having multiple Python interpreters, or multiple Python environments, installed. "pip" and "python" may use different environments. Try installing Tornado like this:

```
python -m pip install tornado
```

Comment: Also ensure that you don't have any file named `tornado.py` within the directory that you are importing it in - usually refrain from having your code filenames the same as library names.

Answer (score 6):

I got rid of this by using following command.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install tornado
```

Comment: question is asked for `python 2.x` and so this won't work.

Comment: Worked for me coz Raspberry Pi3 runs Python v3 by default where as pip install without mentioning the version number specifically would add the module to python 2.x probably.

Comment: For me, it is worked well with sudo python3 -m pip install tornado. Actually sometimes I forget python and python3 differences matter.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the issue while testing tornado for the first time. It was because I named the file as tornado.py (as also mentioned by Mohamed Abdelijelil). I renamed it to tornado_test.py and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

check if tornado module is installed with pip and if you are using a virtualenv check if it's activated

Comment: check if your python file is named tornado.py, if the case you have to change the name of your file because it's make a conflict in python import modules